# dimension of subspace - polynominals evaluated on f

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I need to prove that the dimension of the subspace of endomorphisms

[image]

is less or equal m, if m is the degree of a polynomial p of K[t] \ {0} with p(f) = 0 (f is endomorphism).

In a second step I need to show that the dimension is the minimum of the degrees of polynomials p with p(f)=0.

I know that this must work with linear dependency, but I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ the degree of the polynomial $$P=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k$$
then the set 
$$\mathcal S=\{\operatorname{id},f,\ldots,f^m\}$$
is linearly dependent and spans the subspace $\Bbb K[f]$; indeed if $L(f)\in\Bbb K[f]$  where $L$ is a polynomial then writing the euclidean division of $L$ by $P$:
$$L=QP+R$$
and $\deg (R)<m$ we see that $L(f)=R(f)\in\operatorname{span}(\mathcal S)$.

Hence 
$$\dim \Bbb K[f]<m+1=\# \mathcal S$$
Now  by the previous work we see that the dimension of $\dim \Bbb K[f]$ is less or equal the minimum (say also $m$) of the degrees  of polynomials $P$ with $P(f)=0$ *(and notice that this minimum exists since $\Bbb K[f]$ is a subspace of $L(E)$ which has a finite dimension)*. Finally   if $\dim\Bbb K[f]<m$ then  we can find a polynomial with degree  strictly less than $m$ which annihilates $f$. Contradiction

Comment: Why is L(f) = R(f)? And I don't quite see why p(f)=0 is that important.